# How to Override ScrollViewDidEndDecelerating and find current visible cell ?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a view controller which contains a collectionView:

```
class TagViewController: UIViewController,  UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let post = posts[indexPath.row]
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! SNPostViewCell
        cell.isVideo = post.isVideo
        cell.mediaURL = URL(string: post.mediaURL)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let post = posts[indexPath.row]
        if post.isVideo == true {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "playVideo", sender: nil)
        } else {
            print("is image. might go full screen one day here")
        }
        let bin = self.bins[post.timeStamp]
        print(bin)
    }
    override func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {                //Error: method cannot override from its superclass
        <#code#>
    }

}
```

Although I can override those collectionView functions, it seems that to override scrollViewDidEndDecelerating I specifically need to have an instance of collectionView (and not do it in a view controller)

OK so I made a custom collectionView which inherits from collectionViewController. This overrides scrollViewDidEndDecelerating correctly (the method now DOES override from its superclass), and I am using code inside of it to find the index of the current cell,

```
class PagingCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
...   
 override func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if (self.collectionView.contentOffset.y < 0) {
            self.collectionView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.collectionView.contentOffset.x, 0.0);
        }
        for cell in yourCollectionViewname.visibleCells()  as [UICollectionViewCell]    {
            let indexPath = yourCollectionViewname.indexPathForCell(cell as UICollectionViewCell)

        }
    }

...
}
```

However, as you can see this needs to reference the current index of the collectionView which I wouldn't have defined in the class right? Only in the view Controller where the instance is created and populated...

So I don't really understand where to put this override scrollViewDidEndDecelerating function and how to access the data within it successfully - to find the index.

Comment: Sorry, I’m a little confused. What exactly is your question? Is it how to implement scroll view delegate methods? Is it where to put those methods? Is it how to obtain a reference to the collection view from within those methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
override func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    <#code#>
}
```

... because `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` is *not* an `override` method. It is a *delegate* method.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619417-scrollviewdidenddecelerating

So delete the word `override`, and set `self` as the `delegate` of the `collectionView`, and you're all set.

Comment: Except that `TagViewController` already adopts `UICollectionViewDelegate`. So it doesn’t need to also adopt `UIScrollViewDelegate`.

Comment: @ABeard89 Very sharp eyes! I'll just back that out.

Comment: @ABeard89 But your help helped!

Comment: Always glad to help!